# Distribution of points in SVMs

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

Is that an assumption that in SVMs there is a separation of -1 to +1 for all the sample data points, i.e., if x_p is a positive label point then w.x_p + b >= 1 and if x_n is a negative label point then w.x_n <= -1; where w is the vector perpendicular to separating hyper-plane. I was watching this lecture https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=4&v=_PwhiWxHK8o that raises my doubt. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of SVM that does not allow any positive point to be on negative side of boundary and vice versa, is called [hard margin SVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support-vector_machine#Hard-margin). The version that allows but penalizes this violation is called [soft margin SVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support-vector_machine#Soft-margin). In practice, always soft margin is used since it is unlikely that classes would be perfectly separated, they probably overlap in some regions.